# Parse CloudCode beforeSave object does not have objectID

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I am trying to send a push to a user from Parse Cloud Code every time a new object is created of a certain class, but in the push i need to send the objectId to the user, but it is always null. 
So is the objectId available in beforeSave when a new object is created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the objectId is not available until after the object is saved. However, there is an afterSave() method where you can send the push. Works the same way as beforeSave().

Comment: but i need to know if the object is new and the `isNew` method is only available in beforeSave

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `afterSave` trigger and check for
`request.object.existed()` in there to run your code on new objects.